# Double integral bounded by a domain

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The integral I want to evaluate is $$\int \:\int _D\:\left(x+y\right)dxdy\:$$$$where\:D:\:xy\ge \:2,\:x+y\le \:3$$

I want to know how to find out the domain, I have no idea where to start from or how to make the graph even, any help is much appreciated!

To be clear, I just want to know whats the domain and how did you find it out in order to evaluate the double integral, the actual evaluation of it it's not needed since I know how to do it once I learnt the domain.

Comment: What do you mean by "what's the domain"?  It is clearly $D$.

Comment: Domain D can easily be drawn: it is the region **above** a branch of hyperbola with equation $y=\frac2x$ (the branch which in the first quadrant (x>0,y>0$)) and **under** line with equation $y=-x+3$ (your question should mention that $x>0, y>0$).

Comment: Yes they are non negative i think, i don't know it's the first time i do this type of exercise.
I meant the boundaries of the integral rather the domain, I am not sure what's the correct english term for it sorry.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, I understood now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $xy \ge 2 \implies (x > 0 \land y \ge 2/x) \lor (x < 0 \land y \le 2/x)$

> [image]

---

- $x+y \le 3 \implies y \le 3-x \implies$ the region below the line $y=3-x$.

> [image]

---

- Now, find the intersection of these two.

---

So, as the value of $x$ ranges between $1$ and $2$, the value of $y$ is between $2/x$ and $3-x$.
$$\iint\limits_D(x+y)dxdy = \int\limits_1^2 dx \int\limits_{2/x}^{3-x}(x+y)dy$$

Comment: You should give as well the Desmos instructions you have used in order that next time, the OP can do this work by him/her-self.

Comment: yea, I have already used desmos for this, its (1,2) and (2,1) isnt it, but I don't know if those are the boundaries I should take for when I solve my integral, that's the issue I have since I am quite stupid.

Comment: @tryingtosolvethispain No, you should determine the region. BTW, I guess you assume that $x$ and $y$ are non-negative, otherwise you would have to deal with the infinite region below as well?

Comment: Yes, i think so, its the first time I do this type of exercise. How do I determine the region, I really don't know how

Comment: @tryingtosolvethispain See the edit. I appended more thoughts at the end.

Comment: @tryingtosolvethispain I'm glad that it helped. Let me know if you have more question with the answer.

Comment: No I think I understood, I really appreciated the help thanks!